# Creating html Elements dynamically using ngFor Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Hi everyone I am new to angular. I am trying to create mat-cards for each object in an array however no cards appear.

Html:

```
<mat-card *ngFor="let item of data">
  {{ item.name }}
</mat-card>
```

Typescript:

```
export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  {position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
  {position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'},
  {position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li'},
  {position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be'},
  {position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B'},
  {position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C'},
  {position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N'},
  {position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O'},
  {position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F'},
  {position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne'},
  {position: 11, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne'},
];

export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  data: PeriodicElement[];

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `data` is an empty array. Put something in it and your code might work.

Comment: I see, i know the question is probably gonna get closed but thanks for the help. My issue is that i misunderstood how typescript works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
ngOnInit() {
this.data = ELEMENT_DATA;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're filling the property ELEMENT_DATA not the property data